# (php) I get extra code in "get" method link

Tags: php, sql, methods, get, slug

my 1st question in overflow :)

I have tried to create a table to show all posts from SQL.
I have done the next code:

```
function show_all_posts_in_table(){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM posts";
        $all_posts_content_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_posts_content_query)) {
            $post_id_display = $row['post_id'];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_id_display = $row['post_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_category_display = $row['post_category_id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_title_display = $row['post_title'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_author_display = $row['post_author'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_date_display = $row['post_date'] . "</td>";
            $post_image_display = $row['post_image'];
            echo "<td>" . "<img src= '../images/{$post_image_display}' width='200' height='auto'>" . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_content_display = $row['post_content'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_tags_display = $row['post_tags'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $post_status_display = $row['post_status'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>{$post_id_display}</td>";
            echo "<td> <a href='posts.php?delete={$post_id_display}'>DELETE</a> </td>";
            echo "</tr>";
}
}
```

i see all the posts in the table I made and everything is working fine.

the problem is when I try to delete one of the posts (delete href with "get" method).

for some reason I could not understand, on the address line of the chrome i get an extra `</td>`.

i've been directed to: `posts.php?delete=6</td>`.

can anyone understand why this is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$post_id_display = $row['post_id'] . "</td>";`  will set `$post_id_display` to the `$row['post_id']` and then concatenate `</td>` to it.

There's no need to store these values in separate variables. Just use the `$row` array directly instead.

Change it to:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($all_posts_content_query)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_category_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_title'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_author'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<img src= '../images/" . $row['post_image'] . "' width='200' height='auto'>" . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_content'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_tags'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_status'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['post_id'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='posts.php?delete=" . $row['post_id'] . "'>DELETE</a> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

...and it should work.

Comment: it works great! thank you!
also, can you explain why do i get this td in the slug?

Comment: @ahiadhazan - I did explain the first sentence. You can also read Jeff's answer, which explains it in more detail.

Comment: sorry, just saw it, thank you very much my friend! :)

Answer (score 0):

as extention to @MagnusEriksson's answer just a little test/simplification of what is happening:

What you do right now:

```
$a = "A";
$b = "B";
echo "x" . $a = $b . "y"; // -> xBy
echo " value of A: ".$a; // -> value of A: By
```

This would work:

```
$a = "A";
$b = "B";
echo "x" . ($a = $b) . "y"; // -> xBy
echo " value of A: ".$a;  // -> value of A: B
```

Comment: just got it, thank you very much for your help my friend :)